# Is it bad to pass OUT parameter to procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a procedure with OUT Parameter to get the primary key inserted into the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spProcedureName (
    @Name VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Place VARCHAR(20)
    ,@InsertedId INT = 0 OUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableName (
        NAME
        ,Place
        )
    VALUES (
        @Name
        ,@Place
        );

    SET @InsertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
```

This procedure is used in my C# code. I get the value from the OUT parameter also.

But, This was peer reviewed and asked not to use OUT parameter. He told to change the procedure as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spProcedureName (
    @Name VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Place VARCHAR(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @InsertedId INT = 0;
    INSERT INTO TableName (
        NAME
        ,Place
        )
    VALUES (
        @Name
        ,@Place
        );

    SET @InsertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT @InsertedId;
END;
```

I want to know why it is bad to use OUT parameter. Please let me know. I searched but could not get anything.

P.S : The procedure in the post is just a sample. The ID generated is used in other tables as foreign key in the actual procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there should be a difference.

Comment: @ZoharPeled If you were in the situation what would you choose to do? I mean which one do you think is the right way?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. Personally, I prefer to keep scalar results in out parameters and reserve result sets for truly relational data. Apparently, your peer is of the opposite opinion. In this example where the procedure produces no other result sets, it's not going to make much difference.

Comment: I agree with Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between returning a scalar value in a return parameter vs a result set are purely semantically.

The design decisions guiding which approach to use should be driven primarily by context, but also style and consistency. If your stored procedure already produces a result set, having a return parameter can be a convenient way to also pass back a scalar value to your application.  Some client applications or data access layers may not be well suited to handle a return parameter.  Understanding the client application may contribute to the overall design.  Consistency may also play a role. If typically the stored procedures in your system return a result set for scalar values, and your code is optimized as such, adding a new stored procedure that returns data in a different way may not be an elegant solution and may add complexity.

Overall, understanding all of the pieces in your system and how they interact with your stored procedure will lead to the optimal design approach.